# How do you write applications in multiple languages?

Tags: python, c++, c

Sorry guys if this seems like a really basic question. I understand how to build applications using a programming language. Now, I read that tensorflow is written partly in C/C++ and Python. I'm wondering why this is done and how you can get multiple languages to interface with each other.

Comment: In general, you *write* the implementation in a single language such as C++. Then you *wrap* the interface with bindings to other langauges, such as Python. There are a number of tools and libraries to wrap interfaces such as [swig](http://www.swig.org/tutorial.html)

Comment: [Extending and Embedding the Python Interpreter](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/index.html)

Comment: Read about creating dynamic or shared libraries.  They can be created in any language and used by any language that can interface with them.

Comment: Highly recommend pybind11

Comment: No programming language is well suited to everything.   C and C++ (which are separate languages - there is no such thing as C/C++) are suited well to some tasks, but not others.   Python is better suited to a different set of tasks, and not others.   When the effort of interfacing between code in different languages (say, allowing Python to call a C function) is small compared with the benefits of using each language for tasks they work well for, then an application may well be constructed in multiple languages.

Comment: Maybe this will help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145270/calling-c-c-from-python#145649